# WhiteSpaceCollapse in WPF

Tags: wpf

I'm experimenting with Inkscape's XAML export option, and the code generator incorporates this `WhiteSpaceCollapse` into the markup. I'm having trouble finding the documentation for this, but it won't compile in vanilla WPF. Does anyone know where this comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

google `WhiteSpaceCollapse XAML`. [First Link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1521688)

it's tracked as a bug. Try to manually replace it with `xml:space="preserve"`

Comment: whoops, that wasn't intended as an answer, but a comment. well, I'll leave it

Comment: When I google "WhiteSpaceCollapse XAML", the first link for me is this Stack-Overflow page, and then some site called Codegur.com, which appears to be a reformatting of this page, which is very strange. Nothing else of interest turns up for me. I guess everyone's google results are a bit different.